# Single-item-array json feeds not read by C parser

Tags: c, json, mongodb, parsing, yql

I have a recurring problem with single-item json data sources that are consistently rejected by a C data parser looking for the parent/child structure of a multi-item feed.

Where is it easiest to fix this - on my end, when I create the feeds, or for the C programmer to add a couple lines to also let it accept data that looks like object?

The error message I get is

```
Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty
```

which tells me it looks around the house for children that don't exist, like a nosy aunt.

In case you need to know how the data is processed,  I use yql to standardize various sources so the parser can import everything into the right MongoDB fields.  Everything is generated dynamically a few times a day and I can't do anything about the sources that will only deliver one update at a time.

Here's an example of json rejected because it looks like an object.

```
  {"item":
    {
     "artist":"Morphine",
     "song":"Thursday",
     "station":"WXXX",
     "feeddate":"1438014574000",
     "dttype":"utc"
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The one whose fault it is, has to fix it. Simple. Look up the specification what you are allowed to pass to the parser.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, though maybe I didn't ask the question right.  I know what I'm allowed to pass to the parser - arrays are good, objects are not.   What I don't know is how to make single-item results look like arrays instead of objects.  Do you have any suggestions I can try?

Comment: Wouldn't it be **[** { "artist":...} **]** for an array?